# How to get rid of 4-5cu yards of topsoil/sod/dirt

Tags: excavation, excavator

I'm going to be digging up the top 6-8 inches of an 18 square yard plot (41"x48') of lawn grass (easement strip between sidewalk and road).  The 3-4cuyd volume will probably load as 4-5cuyd. There is no place on the property to place it.  It needs to go.  It has a high clay content.

I could make 8-10 15mi round trips to a business that will take it for $20 per pickup truck load, which would be a lot of extra brute somethingoranother. I like digging with a shovel, but not the hauling and unloading etc.

What are the options to avoid pickup trucking it away myself, but still claim to be king of the neighborhood el cheapos??

It's easy access. Are there tiny excavators that could it, with that and the hauling for essentially the same price as getting hauled?

Comment: Ask your neighbours if they want some soil ?

Comment: Yes, went there.

Comment: Going to try craigslist next.

Comment: People will pay for clean fill. The craigslist recommendation may provide the best response. There's a "Free" section on many/most/all of them and I see fill requests and fill offers on a regular basis.

Comment: Don't wash soil down the drain intentionally - you'll contribute to clogging (more-so because its clay heavy)  and there's a good chance it will clog on your property not down the street.

Comment: How about a nice garden feature on your own property?  A raised flowerbed or vegetable garden could be nice.

Comment: In the U.S.: http://dirtfill.com/

Answer (score 1):

Post it for **FREE** on Craigslist.

People are always looking for fill for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

40 5 gallon buckets per cu yd

Haul off 10 buckets a trip and your pile will be gone in 18-20 trips. Or do it slower. 2bucket a day and you lose 5 yards in 100 days